# How to enable automatic login in KDE from the command line

Tags: command-line, login, kde, login-screen

I received today a new laptop with face recognition. I enabled this for logging into KDE. However, my face is not being detected correctly and I cannot log into the system, since due to a bug, I cannot enter a password. I can however log into the command line. How can I enable aotologin in KDE via the command line?

I am on 18.04

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open in editor file

```
sudo nano /etc/gdm3/custom.conf
```

and add line in section "DAEMON"

```
vi /etc/gdm3/custom.conf

AutomaticLoginEnable=True
AutomaticLogin=REPLACE_YOUR_USERNAME
```

OR

```
sudo nano /etc/sddm.conf
```

and add line in section "DAEMON"

```
Relogin=false
User=REPLACE_YOUR_USERNAME
Session=Kubuntu
```

Comment: There is no /etc/gdm directory.

Comment: @Bruni try gdm3

Comment: Neither. Is KUBUNTU using gdm?

Comment: @Bruni try edit /etc/sddm.conf

Comment: There was no such file, though when I created it, the sddm it worked.

Comment: custom.conf and gddm.conf ave also been replaced by families of  configurations.  I see a pattern here.  That's why the version is essential to the answer.

Comment: I don't have /etc/gdm either. What is the solution, 4 years later? Ubuntu Studio 22.04.3 LTS